# ReactiveVar not getting new value on Tracker.autorun in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-tracker

I'm instantiating a new ReactiveVar:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
   this.var1 = new ReactiveVar(0);
}
```

I'm having a Tracker.autorun force a rerun when the user selects a new year value:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  Tracker.autorun(function() {
  var year = Session.get('chartYear').toString(); // This session is from another template
  // Do stuff 
  ...
  Template.instance().var1.set(new data);
  }
}
```

My helpers to rerun the function:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  function1: function () {
    return Template.instance().var1.get();
}
```

Not sure what's going on but when a year value is selected on first go, everything runs fine. But when the user selects a new year value, a TypeError results:

```
"TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Template.instance().var1')"
```

However, if I replace the ReactiveVars with Sessions instead, everything works fine when the user selects different year values. Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which line is throwing that error (if the following doesn't apply post the full error indicating if this is from the helper or onRendered event, etc).

However I suspect this is from the [`Template.onRendered`](http://Template-onRendered) event, which requires you to access the template instance from the `this` object, like you are in your [`Template.onCreated`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onCreated) event.

- In 'lifecycle' events, e.g. `Template.onRendered`, `Template.onCreated`, `Template.onDestroyed`, the current template instance is the `this` object
- In 'helper' functions, the current template instance is accessed using `Template.instance()`
- In 'DOM' events, e.g. `'click #myButton'(event, instance)`, the current template instance is the second argument passed to the event handler.  [(`Template.instance()` also works here, but convention is to name the second argument 'instance', and use in instead)](http://blazejs.org/guide/reusable-components.html#Use-the-template-instance)

So try changing your `onRendered` function to this:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function() {
  templateInstance = this;
  Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var year = Session.get('chartYear').toString(); // This session is from another template
    // Do stuff 
    ...
    templateInstance.var1.set(newData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Error is coming from the onRendered(). "Exception from Tracker recompute function. TypeError: null is not a object (evaluating 'Template.instance().var1' " I'm using var1 as an example for this post.

Comment: So the above applies then - change `Template.instance()` to `this`

Comment: Changing 'Template.instance()' in onRendered() to 'this' causes the following error: "Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:" and  "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.var1.set')". Also, on first render of the page, no data are present at all.

Comment: ahh, `this` will have changed inside your Tracker.autorun function.  I'll add to the answer above

Comment: Aha. You're a star. So why wouldn't 'Template.instance()' work?

Comment: I'd have to dive into the code to figure out exactly why `Template.instance()` doesn't work here, but given that you are defining a method on an object, the direct way of referring to that object (`this`) is the best way to refer to it rather than via indirection (`Template.instance()`) that is required elsewhere.